# understanding a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I'm trying to solve this question from Ron Larson's linear algebra textbook. But I'm just stuck on how to approach this question. Could someone please at least give me a hint on how to approach this sort of question?

> Suppose $T:\unicode{x211D}^2\rightarrow\unicode{x211D}^2$ such that
> $T(1,0)=(0,1)$ and $T(0,1)=(1,0)$.
>
> i)Determine $T(x,y)$ for $(x,y)$ in $\unicode{x211D}^2$
>
> ii)Give a geometric description of $T$

Thank you

Comment: $(x,y)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $(x,y)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)$. Therefore, because $T$ is linear, $$T(x,y)=xT(1,0)+yT(0,1)=x(0,1)+y(1,0)=(y,x)$$
So $T$ maps the point $(x,y)$ to the point $(y,x)$. What does this do geometrically?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix associated with $T$ is $\begin{bmatrix}{0}&{1}\\{1}&{0}\end{bmatrix}$, geometrically is a reflection with respect to $y = x$